# How do I scrape all the job titles from a LinkedIn search result?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get all the job titles from the search results from a LinkedIn. However, I only get the first seven when iterating through the element XPATHs. I looked at all the other links to make sure that their xPATH matched mine. Any idea how I can get all the titles of each job posting on a page?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
import time

EMAIL = ""
PW = ""

chrome_driver_path = "D:\chromedriver.exe"
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_AL=true&f_PP=100761630%2C103366113%2C105829038&keywords=python%20developer&sortBy=R")

# Store the ID of the original window
original_window = driver.current_window_handle
# Check we don't have other windows open already
assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1

# Clicks the signin button on LinkedIn.
sign_in = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/a[2]")
sign_in.click()

# Waits until the sign in with Google button is clickable on page to avoid not interactable exception.
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sign-in-with-google-button"))).click()

# Wait for the new window or tab
wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

# Loop through until we find a new window handle
for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
    if window_handle != original_window:
        driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
        break

# Enters username and password into Google sign-in and clicks next.
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierId"]'))).send_keys(EMAIL)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button/span'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input'))).send_keys(PW)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button/span'))).click()

# Selects main screen again.
driver.switch_to.window(original_window)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember213"]'))).click()

# Gets list of all job titles.

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
job_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div/ul/li/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a')


for job in job_list:
    print(job.text)



# Delays closing of browser by undetected-chrome driver.
time.sleep(10000)

driver.quit()
```